# Run VLC Player from Javascript using windows command

Tags: javascript, windows, command-line, vlc

I have a VLC player installed on a windows 2012 server machine. I want to transcode my input .ogg stream to .mp3 using the vlc player. I have a web app which produce .ogg stream and when a user clicks on convert button on my web app i want to execute a javascript which should take .ogg stream as my input and execute a windows command to vlc player installed on the server and starts the trancoding. I have the windows command to transcode a .ogg to .mp3 using vlc but I want this to happen programatically. On a button click how to access command line and execute a windows command?

Comment: Should the destination system be only Windows?

Comment: @StanE Yes. It will be windows. Don't worry about destination. I might or might not save the transcoded file. I just need a way how can i execute a windows command from a javascript. Or if there is another better way to execute a windows command from a web app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible with JavaScript without manipulating the client system. It would be too dangerous if every website would be able to execute commands on the client system. JavaScript in browsers runs in a sandbox, which means that it cannot access the system and execute commands.

But if you have the possibility to manipulate the system, then you could do this, I think. At least in Windows. You could add a new pseudo protocol to the windows registry and link it to the VLC player. Similar to how other apps do it, for example torrent clients, jDownloader or IRC clients. Then you could enter or open a popup with such a protocol address, like

```
vlcurl:your-data-comes-here
```

One working example is the e-Mail pseudo protocol, that you can try in your browser right now:

```
mailto:test%40example.com?subject=Hello%20you
```

**Here is an example:**

But pay attention! This can make the client system vulnerable for attacks from the web. I just show it as an example and I wouldn't suggest to use this method. Also, this works not in all browsers. Some browsers don't handle the registry system setting at all and some will show you a dialog that you have to accept. So the capabilities are limited. A reg file example:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vlcurl]
@="VLC player URL"
"FriendlyTypeName"="VLC player URL"
"URL Protocol"=""
"EditFlags"=dword:00000002

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vlcurl\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vlcurl\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vlcurl\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vlcurl\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe\" \"%1\""
```

You would need to edit the last line. Then you could execute the URL I wrote above ("vlcurl:your-data-comes-here").

Another way would be to use your own browser plugin / addon like flash, which bypasses the sandbox of the browser (afaik).